# Missing Dolphin context menu icons in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: dolphin

I have installed Dolphin and Krusader to navigate faster than Nautilus.
(I am happy with them, please do not advice another one)
But, when I right click, **I see a context menu with no icons.** In normal Kubuntu OS (not Ubuntu), there are icons in right click menu.
Could you help me how I could add this icons to context menu?

Comment: You're running Dolphin in Ubuntu right? did you used Gnome Tweak Tool to add Icons to the Menus?

Comment: Yes, Ubuntu 12.04 as I have wrote. Also, I have Tried Tweak tool, but it did not work. Thank you..